# Delphi: Hiding/showing TWinControl objects in a form is pretty slow. How to get it faster?

Tags: performance, delphi, vcl

I have simple VCL form application in Delphi XE5. In the main form there are hudreds of TEdit components. Now I realized that setting visibility of all these edits is pretty slow. It takes ca 1 second on my computer while they are hidden/shown.

Please note that this is sample intended only for demostrate the issue. I know that this can be solved by inserting edits to a panel and hiding/showing the panel. But this is not possible in our application where edits are inserted to a form by an end user. Also we don't know which edits visibility will be controlled.

How to get it faster?

Note that when I use TLabel (TGraphicControl) instead of TEdit (TWinControl) then it is fast!

```
procedure TForm1.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: TControl;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    C := Controls[i];
    if C.ClassName <> 'TCheckBox' then
      C.Visible := CheckBox1.Checked;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  C: TEdit;
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 60 do
    for j := 0 to 20 do
    begin
      C := TEdit.Create(Self);
      C.Width := 40;
      C.Left := 20 + 50 * j;
      C.Top := 50 + 25 * i;
      C.Parent := Self;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Why would it not be possible to use a panel?

Comment: Did you read my question properly?

Comment: Can you call `DisableAlign` / `EnableAlign` after and before?

Comment: You can use *LockWindowUpdate*. It will stop the flickering and will shorten the time a little.

Comment: @Sotirca, rather `WM_SETREDRAW`. `LockWindowUpdate` is not for this purpose.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound yes, but this doesn't help.

Comment: @SotircaMihaitaGeorge thanks, but this doesn't help.

Comment: It actually helps a little bit, at least on my tests, got a little faster using your example

Comment: Another ideea. Put all edits on a panel, hide the panel, hide/show the edits and show the panel.

Comment: IMHO, if it's possible for the end user to add edits to a form you can also make it possible to add them to a panel...

Comment: I think I did. I don't see what's hard about making a panel be the parent. Perhaps you need to open your mind a little. Or explain why this option really isn't possible. Nobody other than you can see why that should be so.

Comment: In our application there is a design form where user can place our components to create a GUI. We have absolutely no control on what he make - how many components he put in the form and how he design them. Unfortunatelly there is no possibility to use a panels at all. The visibility of componnets is controled from an external system. We only know that in case of TGraphicControl there is no performance problem.

Comment: If you really cannot parent them on a panel, you can still create a client aligned panel and cover them by it. That way you won't need to hide them.

Comment: @TLama Parenting is not solution for me. We don't know which edits visibility will be controlled. Interesting is that if I use TLabel (TGraphicControl) instead of TEdit then it is fast.

Comment: You should edit the question to make that clear. Also, use `is` rather than ClassName.

Comment: Does the user actually type in these edit controls? Or do you just use them to display text?

Comment: @JerryDodge yes, he does :-)

Comment: Are you trying to hide them at runtime when the form is visible or can you hide them before the form is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Your controls are parented directly by the form. Instead create a panel with `alClient` align and set the panel's `Parent` to be the form.

When you create the edit controls, make their `Parent` be the panel. When you wish to hide the edit controls, hide the panel.

If you don't want to, or cannot, make such a drastic change, then you can batch the changes with `BeginDeferWindowPos`, `DeferWindowPos` and `EndDeferWindowPos`. You might have code along these lines:

```
const
  Flags = SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOSIZE or 
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_HIDEWINDOW;
var
  i: Integer;
  wpi: HDWP;
  wnd: HWND;
begin
  wpi := BeginDeferWindowPos(10);
  Win32Check(wpi <> 0);
  Try
    for i := 1 to 10 do begin
      wnd := (FindComponent('Edit' + IntToStr(i)) as TWinControl).Handle;
      Win32Check(DeferWindowPos(wpi, wnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Flags) <> 0);
    end;
  Finally
    Win32Check(EndDeferWindowPos(wpi));
  End;
end;
```

Clearly you'll use a different mechanism to obtain your window handles, but I don't feel that detracts from this example.

Comment: Parenting is not solution for me. We don't know which edits visibility will be controlled.

Comment: The question doesn't make that clear. Anyway, use DeferWindowPos.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question. Sorry I don't know how to use DeferWindowPos in mys case.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Have you any experience of the Win32 API? There's some discussion here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/06/436043.aspx Obviously you are not moving windows, but hiding them. So you'll want to use the flags to suppress movement, resizing and z-order changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know. In our case we resolving the visibility on component side in a timer handler. In this handler we determine if show or hide the component. So switching to the DeferWindowPos takes lot of time and work. But thanks again for the advice.

Comment: There's no mention of timers in the question. You've just got a straight loop. I can't comment on these timers with no information. I have a suspicion that the real problem lies in your code which only you can see. If I were you I'd try to re-create the issue in a test bed. I have a feeling that you don't yet understand it fully.

Comment: You are right. I tried to explain my issue on the most easiest sample as possible. The real application is much more complicated (in total almost million of lines). Sometime it is quict difficult to find out which factor can be important. Thanks again for you attention.

Comment: My advice is for your next step to work hard to isolate the issue so that you know for sure what the problem is, and that you can identify whether or not candidate solutions will address the real problem. Then you won't waste time re-working the complex project only to find no benefit. That's the big danger in front of you.

Comment: I try to create more specific sample. Please be patient :-)